# To obtain a range of particular value form a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Objective:**
To obtain sum of the integers from a list, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

**Input Master List**

```
a=[4, 5, 6, 7, 9,2, 6,8,9]
```

**My code so far**

```
z6_ind=[]
z9_ind=[]
z69_ind=[]
x=None

for i,v in enumerate(a):
    if v==6:
        z6_ind.append(i)
    if v==9:
        z9_ind.append(i)

print(z6_ind. z9_ind)
```

My idea is to obtain the indexes of the master list in terms of separate lists (eg. z6_ind, z9_ind and finally the problematic z69_ind which should contain the range in terms of [[2,4],[6,8]] that should be excluded from the master list while sum calculation.

From above script, it gives z9_ind equals to [4, 8] whereas z6_ind equals to [2, 6].

Thanks !

Comment: Typo: Replace *z9_ind equals to [2, 6]* by *z6_ind equals to [2, 6]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I caught it correctly, but do you want this code?

```
a = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2, 6, 8, 9]

sigma = 0
exc_ind = []
flag = False
for ind, item in enumerate(a):
    if item == 6 and not flag:
        flag = True
        exc_ind.append([])
        exc_ind[-1].append(ind)
    elif item == 9 and flag:
        exc_ind[-1].append(ind)
        flag = False
    elif not flag:
        sigma += item

print(sigma)
print(exc_ind)
```

The result:

```
11
[[2, 4], [6, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks Hermis, yes it is very helpful that you have given the solution. In case if I want to get the band of 6,x,9 from list 'a', how do i do it?

Comment: I added 'and not flag' to the first if condition to avoid the situation where 6 appears again before 9.

Comment: Trying to figure out how https://i.imgur.com/xNhZ6bY.png is putting everything in first sublist whereas https://i.imgur.com/qQ9sR6v.png in individual ones.

Comment: In the first one, the index [0] indicates the already filled 'List' whereas in the second one the index [-1] always indicates the empty List component just initialized which is not indexed yet. .append() method automatically chooses whether it literally appends a new value with increased index or creates an index to the empty List.

Answer (score 1):

A verbose version with generator:

```
a=[4, 5, 6, 7, 9,2, 6,8,9]

def iterate(iterable):
    stop = False
    for i in iterable:
        if i == 6:
            if stop == False:
                stop = True
                continue
        elif i == 9:
            if stop == True:
                stop = False
                continue
        if stop == False:
            yield i

print(sum(iterate(a))) # will sum 4, 5 and 2
```

Prints:

```
11
```

Comment: Thanks very much Andrej ! I would highly appreciate if you could guide me how is it possible to evaluate z69_ind as per my above code as I am still learning

Comment: @Suvo You can do `for z6, z9 in zip(z6_ind, z9_ind):
    z69_ind.append([z6, z9])` Then z69_ind will be `[[2, 4], [6, 8]]`. But what if you have sequence `a = [1, 2, 6, 6, 9]`? Notice 6 is in the middle.

Comment: Trying to figure out how i.imgur.com/xNhZ6bY.png is putting everything in first sublist whereas i.imgur.com/qQ9sR6v.png in individual ones

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the part of your code:

```
a_sum = sum(a)
to_reduce = 0
for (bot,top) in zip(z6_ind, z9_ind):
    to_reduce += sum(a[bot:top+1])
```

Basically zip "pairs" both indexes and get sums between them - numbers you want to reduce a_sum by:

```
result = a_sum - to_reduce
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 9,2, 6,8,9])
ind1 = np.where(a == 6)[0]
ind2 = np.where(a == 9)[0]
indices = [item for i in zip(ind1, ind2) for item in np.arange(i[0], i[1]+1)]
result = sum(a) -  sum(a[indices])
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
11
```